# Validate uniqueness among subset

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a "simple" rails issue I can't find any documentation about and I hope someone out there can point me in the right direction.

I have a model, called category with a state attribute. I want to be able to validate the uniqueness of the category name among all the records with state different from 'void'.

To achieve so, right now I have created a custom validator but I guess there is a built-in option to achieve so. Am I right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at conditional validations. For example, if you had a `.not_void?` method on your model, you could use:

```
validates :category, uniqueness: true, if: :not_void?
```

There are also options for using a string (which gets `eval`'d) or a proc -- check out the [Validations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless) for more info.

---

**EDIT:** New answer based on clarified question

From my understanding, it may be a little difficult to achieve what you're after with the built in validators, as you want to validate uniqueness across any state that is not void. It is possible to use the `:scope` option to check limit the records uniqueness is determined against, so you could look at adding an extra boolean field to the table and use that to determine uniqueness. For example, if you added a `void` attribute to your table/model, you could get the behaviour you wanted with

```
# category.rb
before_validation :set_void

def set_void
  self.void = (state == "void")
end

validates :category, uniqueness: { scope: :void }, unless: :void
```

This would automatically update the `void` attribute before validating, and then validate that the category's name is unique compared to all other non-void categories (as long as that category's own state is not void).

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I'm afraid I haven't been clear enough. 

From my understanding the code you suggested is going to trigger the validation if the category I wish to save has a state other than void but this is not what I want to achieve. I want to validate the category name against all the name of categories that are in a state that is not 'void'. If instance let us say I have 2 categories

{name: "a", state: "x"} 
{name: "b", state: "void"}

If now I try to add a category with name "a" the category should not be valid however I should be able to save a category with "b" as name.

Comment: Cool, I misunderstood. I've added another solution, which I think is probably as close as you'll be able to get with the in built validations, although it would require adding an extra boolean attribute to your model, which may or may not be an option for you.

Comment: Thanks for the updated solution. Not sure it is better than the custom validator I have now but I appreciate your help. Anyway I will give it  a try soon.